# Programmatically add UINavigationController in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I currently have a view set up as the following:

```
@interface BlogViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UITableView *mainTableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *mainTableView;
```

As you can see, it has a UITableView inside of it that I load all of my data to. However, when I call the following function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SingleBlogViewController *viewController = [[SingleBlogViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    //[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

nothing happens. For some reason my `UITableView` inside of my `UIViewController` isn't pushing the view. Is this because it isn't a `UITableViewController`? I tried changing it to that, and it still didn't work.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How is BlogViewController itself shown?  Was it pushed or is it the root view controller of a navigation controller?

Comment: It is a modal view that's shown using presentModalViewController:

Comment: how are you adding your uiviewcontroller to your program? Through a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 26):

I found the first parts of [this blog post](http://theolternative.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-tips-navigation-and-tap-bar-controller/) useful for showing how to create and use a UINavigationController programmatically without Interface Builder.

Some of the things I wish the docs and tutorials would have stressed to me:

- When you create the `UINavigationController` you get a UIView and UINavigationBar for free (i.e. you don't need to separately add them and figure out how to hook them together).
- You add the `myUINavigationController.view` property as the "main" view and then push/pop `UIViewController`s onto the UINavigationController and they will automatically show up as visible in the `myUINavigationController.view` UIView.
- When you push a `UIViewController` onto a `UINavigationController`, the `UIViewController.navigationController` is filled in.  If you haven't pushed the view onto the navigation controller, I'm guessing that property is empty.
- The time/place to programmatically add buttons to the `UINavigationBar` is not when and where you construct the `UINavigationController`, but rather by the individual `UIViewController`s when they are loaded as you push onto the `UINavigationController`.
- I only had to add a "Done" button to the `UINavigationController`'s `UINavigationBar` in the `viewDidLoad` method of the first `UIViewController` pushed onto the `UINavigationController`.  Any `UIViewController` I pushed on *top* of that first view automatically had a "back" button in the to navigate to the covered up `UIViewController`.
- If you set the `title` property of your `UIViewController` before you put it on the `UINavigationController`'s stack.  The `UINavigationBar`s title will be the title of your view.  As well any "back" buttons will automatically name the view you are returning to instead of generically saying "back".

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother, but the blog post you give is dead, any chance to find it otherwhere? thanks

Comment: @armnotstrong try this https://web.archive.org/web/20120501094236/http://theolternative.wordpress.com:80/2009/04/27/iphone-dev-tips-navigation-and-tap-bar-controller/

Answer (score -3):

Please visit "[How to add UINavigationController Programmatically](http://www.uinnoblog.com/uinavigationcontroller-programmatically.html)"

Please visit above link & get all information regarding UINavigationController.

UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController, but unlike UIViewController it’s not usually meant for you to subclass. This is because navigation controller itself is rarely customized beyond the visuals of the nav bar. An instance of UINavigationController can be created either in code or in an XIB file with relative ease.

Comment: I think the question is how to create a UINavigaionController inside a UIViewController, the above link only shows how to create a UINavigationController in the AppDelegate main class.