# iPhone SDK - Add a UINavigationController Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone project which currently does not have a `UINavigationController` in it. Instead I swap views by handling the view hierarchy myself. However - as you're probably aware - this is bad practice, so I am trying to figure out how to implement a `UINavigationController` into my current app. I can obviously start my project over and use an Xcode template, but I really don't want to do this.

**There must be a way to do this programmatically.** But I can't figure out what code needs to go in the AppDelegate. Does anyone have any experience with this? I am at a loss at the moment.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeap.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
   navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
   MyViewController *firstController=[[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [navController pushViewController:firstController animated:NO];
   [window addSubview: navController.view];
} 
- (void) dealloc
{
   ...  
   [navController release];
   ...
}
```

It's a quite common question, have a look at this too....
[Programmatically add UINavigationController in UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400901/programmatically-add-uinavigationcontroller-in-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: I think you should put animated:yes. because most of time. we want controller animates before move to new view. thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

// application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode 4 in the interface editor, open the initial view controller, and then select
 'editor > embed in >navigation controller'

Answer (score 1):

example of creating and releasing a navigation controller:

```
UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navCon pushViewController:yourViewController animated:NO];
[navCon release];
```

Answer (score 1):

![I added navigation controller into my tab bar project and it is working perfectly

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];


UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UIViewController *viewController3 = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];


self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2,viewController3];


self.navigationController= [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

//  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


return YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem using this.

```
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
 {
      navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
      MyViewController *firstController=[[MyViewController alloc] init];
      self.window.rootViewController = firstController;
      [self.window addSubview navController.view];

 }
```