# iphone app-Adding a view by removing previous view

Tags: iphone, xcode, stack, addsubview

i am using two view says A and B. I need to go to view B on pressing a button in View A so in the button action listener defined in view A, i wrote

```
    -(IBAction)bt:(id)sender
    {
      B *mB=[[B alloc]initWithNib:@"B" bundle:nil];
      [self.view addSubView:mB.view];
    }
```

so that means view B has been added over view A. Thus, both the views remain on stack which consume memory i think.
Is their any way by which pressing the button in view A, it is removed and then view B is added??

Answer (score 0):

you can use removeFromSuperview to remove view A

```
    [view_A_Object removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: But if I do this,View A is removed and View B is not added.

Comment: can you show me how you are doing this ? in the same function you just have to remove A from superview, or if you want to go back to view A later then use UINavigationController

Comment: i am not implementing navigation controller in my application.
-(IBAction)bt:(id)sender
    {
      B *mB=[[B alloc]initWithNib:@"B" bundle:nil];
      [self.view addSubView:mB.view];
      [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

Comment: I think B is also a viewController not a view. in that case you are adding it in a wrong way. You should use NavigationController. If you dont want to show navigationBar you can hide it.

Comment: both these views are sub class of UIViewController.can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129986/iphone-sdk-add-a-uinavigationcontroller-programmatically

Comment: the post is quite useful.I have many views in my application and i am switching among the view by addSubView only?Won't the entire structure gets changed if i add navigation bar controller?

Comment: you can add views using addSubview but you cant add viewCOntroller's view like that.

Comment: My views in .h files are defined like this, for eg. @interface Create_Inventory_Item : UIViewController